# Avoid Page_Load to effect my array, using AJAX

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a textbox that the user suppose to place numbers on it,
and after he push the button, the number should pass to an array.

and each number and button pushed, should be saved in this array in order (for example : 3 , 4, 5, ....)

The problem is, that each time I push the button, then `page_load` occurs. I have this code :

```
    protected string[] CurrentArr;

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (CurrentArr != null)
        {
            CurrentArr = (string[])Session["CurrentArr"];      
        }
        else
            CurrentArr = new string[length];
```

which `CurrentArr` is the array that change over time.

I tried to solved it with AJAX as well :

```
<asp:ScriptManager runat="server" ID="sm">
    </asp:ScriptManager>

    <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="update">
        <ContentTemplate>
        <input type="text" class="response" id="how_many" name="guess" placeholder="Enter your guess..." />
        <asp:Button runat="server" class="button red" id="generate" name="generate" value="Generate!" OnClick="guess_Click" />
        <asp:Button runat="server" class="button red" id="win" name="win" value="you won"   />
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

but it has no effect over my array (although my page doesnt post back...)

anyone has a solution ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using an UpdatePanel, it is inherently AJAXified. Just add a trigger section to catch the button click:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="update">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <input type="text" class="response" id="how_many" name="guess" placeholder="Enter your guess..." />
        <asp:Button runat="server" class="button red" id="generate" name="generate" value="Generate!" OnClick="guess_Click" />
        <asp:Button runat="server" class="button red" id="win" name="win" value="you won"   />
    </ContentTemplate>
    <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="generate" EventName="Click" />
    </Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

The problem that you're probably running into is that your array isn't persisting through the postbacks. Try what you and ed were getting at, getting and setting from the session. I prefer not to use old school arrays. Consider a list, they are more versatile. And if you specifically need an array at the end then just use myList.ToArray();

```
private List<int> CurrentArr = new List<string>();

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(Session["CurrentArr"] != null)
    {
        //if there is something stored in the session variable then grab that as a working array
        CurrentArr = (List<string>)Session["CurrentArr"];
    }
    else
    {
        //if not, then initialize one
        CurrentArr = new List<string>();
        Session["CurrentArr"] = CurrentArr;
    }
}

protected void guess_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //get reference to the button clicked like you said in your question
    var btnMyButton = sender as Button; 
    btnMyButton.Enabled = false; //example of using the reference, disable the button that was clicked

    //add the value of your text box to the array/list, sort, then update the session
    this.CurrentArr.Add(txtYourTextBox.Text);
    this.CurrentArr.Sort();
    Session["CurrentArr"] = this.CurrentArr;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Of course, `Load` is part of an ASP.Net's Page [life cycle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx).

See [Page.IsPostBack](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.ispostback.aspx) to have more control on what methods you want, or don't want to run depending on the request type (is it a postback or not).

In the code above, this is probably what you meant:

```
    if (Session["CurrentArr"] != null)
    {
        CurrentArr = (string[])Session["CurrentArr"];
    }
    else
    {
        CurrentArr = new string[length]; //where is length defined?
        Session["CurrentArr"] = CurrentArr;
    }
```